# How to modify/update the internal state of an object passed by const reference

Tags: c++, vector, pass-by-const-reference

Passing an object by const reference means we can't modify any of it's members. But suppose the object contains a `vector<string>` member. How do we write const methods to read the contents of the `vector<string>` member assuming that a `vector<string>::iterator` member is also needed and must be updated after every read to point to the next element in the vector?

Is this possible, or is there another method in this situation? That is, don't modify the contents of the passed by const reference object, but the object should be able to update it's internal state (i.e. next element in the vector to be read).

Comment: Can you use `vector<string>::const_iterator` to iterate over the vector instead?

Comment: I'm trying to modify the iterator, which is a member of an object passed by const reference (i.e. I can't modify it). Declare the member as mutable seems to be the answer, as others have pointed out.

Comment: If you want to modify it, why are you passing it as `const&`?

Comment: I actually want to read it, but I don't know how to except keep an iterator as a member of the passed by const reference object and increment it after each read. Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the keyword `mutable`. A mutable member variable is modifyable within a `const` member method. You can read about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv). An example:

```
class A
{
    std::vector< int > v_;
    mutable std::vector< int >::const_iterator current_;

public:
    int get() const // note the const
    {
        assert( !v_.empty() );
        if( current_ == v_.end() ) current_ = v_.begin();
        return *current_++;
    }
};
```

Note you still need `const_iterator` as the vector itself is const and hence `v_.begin()` does not give you a normal iterator. You *could* fix this by marking the vector itself also as `mutable`, then you could use `iterator`.

Here's a complete [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8132e862cd2f198).

Comment: it_ should be current_, right? Yes, that sounds like the solution I was looking for. But I'm getting an "error: no match for 'operator='" when I try to set the iterator at the beginning of the vector (it_ = v_.begin()) inside the const method.

Comment: Answers the question, but my hack-o-meter is twitching.  Can't upvote as it skirts what is likely the *real* problem.

Comment: @JohnDibling Understandable. For the OP I think it's important to know about the existance of `mutable` first, but it's hard to tell whether or not it's a *good* solution in his case. The problem description itself looked kind of odd to me, in real-life I'd question the design that lead to this question first :)

Comment: Ok, making the passed by const reference object into a member of the object it was passed into a better solution? I was trying to keep my code as modular as possible. If it's a beast then I accept the punishment :) Is the use of mutable frowned upon?

Comment: @Mihai Generally, using `mutable` is sometimes good and sometimes a sign of bad design. With the information we have about your problem, I really can't tell. I would think that it's probably *not* the best solution here, but I don't have enought information to offer a better alternative. I suggest you learn about how `mutable` works and then you need to make your own decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a member you wish to modify at `const` methods - declare them `mutable`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do it: If you want to have semantics like first(), next(), last() for iterating a container, create a proxy:

```
Proxy iteration() const { return Proxy(*this); }
```